# Interval training versus linear training

Tags: running, walking, interval-training

What are the pros of interval training over same intensity training over the same period?

For example, I walk for 1 min @6kmph and then run for 2 mins @9km/hr, repeat for 10 minutes.

Contrast this with walk @6kmph for 2 mins + run @9kmph for 8 mins.

Which style should I prefer for better workout?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Jack Daniels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0736054928), the difference is the following:

- interval training aims to increase your [VO2MAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max) by targeting high intensities, which can't be maintained for a longer period. By design it achieves to maximize the overall volume for those very high intensities because you have breaks between each interval.
- longer (several kilometres) tempo runs aims to increase your [lactate threshold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactate_threshold) by targeting a little bit lower intensities.

Also see [training intensities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Daniels_%28coach%29#Training_intensities).

Comment: +1 for "according to Jack Daniels" :) Old No. 7 is always right

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer. Your individual response to high intensity training (HIT) might be in parts genetically determined. You might be anything from a non-responder or a good responder. Watch last half [a BBC documentary](http://video.pbs.org/video/2364989581), "The Truth About Exercise" with Michael Mosley, for more details as I just did (and stumbled upon your question) If you are a "good responder", HIT will probably work very efficiently on you, and doing little HIT/week will suffice to get good results.

[Using molecular classification to predict gains in maximal aerobic capacity following endurance exercise training in humans](http://jap.physiology.org/content/108/6/1487.full)

It's a field of active research. There is only (?) one study with few participants.

These genetic tests mentioned in the documentary are not available to the general public, AFAIK.